# Is there a possibility to restore a broken connection?

Tags: websocket

I'm developing a real-time game server with WebSocket.

Recently, I've got to know there's a possibility that a connection is broken but server and client both unaware of it. Link : https://github.com/websockets/ws#how-to-detect-and-close-broken-connections

The question is...

- **Q1**. Is there a possibility to restore a broken connection? So below sequence could happen

1. ==WebSocket connection **established**==
2. Server **->** Client : Data1 frame
3. Server **->** Client : ping frame
4. Server **<--** Client : pong frame
5. ==Connection **broken** but nobody notified==
6. Server **->x** Client : Data2 frame
7. ==Connection **restored** but nobody notified==
8. Server **->** Client : ping frame
9. Server **<--** Client : pong frame
10. ==**Connection still alive but Data2 not transferred...**==

- **Q2.** If possible, then how could detect broken connection? Is there an ideal ping-pong period time?

Comment: With websockets you must be ready to handle arbitrary connection closing from the client side

Comment: (@Bercovici Adrian) But the document says connection may broken but server and client both may not be notified. So it suggests use ping-pong frame twice and manually close the connection. And I wonder if there's a possibility that the broken connection restored between two ping-pong frames.

Comment: You should periodically send PING frames and if PONG frames are not sent within a reasonable amount of time (2s), you should close the connection and reconnect (resume). This will allow you to detect "zombied" connections and other similar events.